# How to write to dags directory from Cloud Composer webserver?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm writing Cloud Composer plugin and I need to create DAG in runtime. How can I create DAG file from webserver or how can I access bucket ID from plugin code(so I can use gcs client and just upload DAG)? I tried code below and it doesn't work, I don't get any exceptions but also I don't see any results:

```
dag_path = os.path.join(settings.DAGS_FOLDER, dag_id + '.py')
with open(dag_path, 'w') as dag:
    dag.write(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to read bucket ID from [Cloud Composer env variable](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables)

Answer (score 1):

You may either use the [Environment Variables](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables), or you may make use of the API's provided by [GCloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/).

```
gcloud composer environments describe --format=json --project=<project-name> --location=<region> <cluster-name>
```

This would return the details of the cloud composer cluster.
It would have the dag location under the key `dagGcsPrefix`

The format of `dagGcsPrefix` would be `gs://<GCSBucket>/dags`

Comment: Thanks. I encountered next problem- service account connected to webserver doesn't have permission to write to dags folder. So the question is: does worker has permissions to write to dags folder and if that is so, how can I declare job for worker from webserver?(maybe by creating and triggering DAG at runtime, which save specified string to GCS bucket?)